# any way to emulate permissions with sshfs?

Tags: sshfs

I have a directory structure where lots of data are stored and permissions are important. I also have a rsync.net account. I am investigating the possibility to use the rsync.net storage for the directory structure.

Using sshfs would be a solution, but the obvious problem is that file permissions will not be stored on the rsync.net account. Are there ways to emulate those permissions somehow?

Answer (score 0):

mount a directory in rsync.net using sshfs

use cryfs to mount that directory

a drawback is that cryfs asks for an encryption password on mount time

there is a (unmerged) pull request to cryfs to handle that https://github.com/cryfs/cryfs/pull/314

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but it might be useful to anyone reading this to learn that the rsync command has a --fake-super argument that allows you to retain ownerships and permissions on a remote filesystem that you are not root on.

I have an rsync.net account, like you do, and I use --fake-super successfully with my rsync commands.

There are some other recipes and solutions for this in an rsync.net account and with encrypted, chunking backup tools like 'borg' and 'duplicacy', etc., it sort of becomes a moot point because you're storing encrypted chunks ... but if you want to plain old rsync to cloud storage and perhaps mount and browse it later, with sshfs, you can use --fake-super.